# CREATE SUBSCRIPTION ... WITH (create_slot = true) cannot be executed from a function"}

Tags: postgresql

I almost never use superuser.  In rare cases that I use a function that executes the command with SECURITY DEFINER permissions.  However, a subscriber cannot be executed inside a function.  What is a workaround for this without create_slot= false?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.exec_su(text)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' 
SECURITY DEFINER
AS $BODY$
BEGIN 
    EXECUTE $1;
END 
$BODY$; 

select public.exec_su('CREATE SUBSCRIPTION n1_subscription CONNECTION 'host=pg12x_aaa port=5432 user=rep password=aaa dbname=aaa' PUBLICATION n1_publication;');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the two work arounds.  Either do it outside of a function (and outside of a transaction block), or do it with create_slot=false.  There are no extra choices.

Comment: Hello Did create subscription work for you here , if yes then how , I am facing same issue